# styled-components: The component ... has been created dynamically

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to create a custom SVG icon component. As you all know, SVGs are treated slightly differently from normal HTML elements in react.

Therefore, I can't really just define it outside the render function as I normally do. This is what I have right now:

SvgIcon.js

```
const SvgIcon = ({ stroke, fill, size, icon: Icon, className }) => {
  const StyledIcon = styled(Icon).attrs({
    viewBox: `0 0 24 24`,
  })`
    path {
      ${({ custom_stroke, theme }) =>
        custom_stroke &&
        `stroke: ${calculateColor({ color: custom_stroke, theme })};`}
      ${({ custom_fill, theme }) =>
        custom_fill &&
        `fill: ${calculateColor({ color: custom_fill, theme })};`}
    }
    height: ${({ size }) => calculateSize({ size })};
    width: ${({ size }) => calculateSize({ size })};
  `;

  return (
    <StyledIcon
      className={className}
      size={size}
      custom_fill={fill}
      custom_stroke={stroke}
    />
  );
};

SvgIcon.propTypes = {
  stroke: PropTypes.oneOf(Object.values(SVG_ICON_COLORS)),
  fill: PropTypes.oneOf(Object.values(SVG_ICON_COLORS)),
  size: PropTypes.oneOf(Object.values(SVG_ICON_SIZES)),
  icon: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
};

export default SvgIcon;
```

Which is used like this:

```
import { ReactComponent as ArrowUpIcon } from '../ui/icons/arrow-up.svg';
<SvgIcon icon={ArrowUpIcon} size={"small"} stroke={"blue"} fill={"green"} />
```

However, in the console, styled-components is complaining:

```
The component SvgIcon__StyledIcon with the id of "SvgIcon__StyledIcon-sc-77lkhb-0" has been created dynamically.
You may see this warning because you've called styled inside another component.
To resolve this only create new StyledComponents outside of any render method and function component.
```

How would I make a custom SvgIcon component without the warnings?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just wrapping the SVG in a div and accessing the styles through CSS

```
const IconWrapper = styled.div`
  display: inline-block;
  svg {
    path {
      ${({ custom_stroke, theme }) =>
        custom_stroke &&
        `stroke: ${calculateColor({ color: custom_stroke, theme })};`}
      ${({ custom_fill, theme }) =>
        custom_fill &&
        `fill: ${calculateColor({ color: custom_fill, theme })};`}
    }
    height: ${({ size }) => calculateSize({ size })};
    width: ${({ size }) => calculateSize({ size })};
  }
`;

const SvgIcon = ({ stroke, fill, size, icon: Icon }) => (
  <IconWrapper size={size} custom_fill={fill} custom_stroke={stroke}>
    <Icon viewBox="0 0 24 24" />
  </IconWrapper>
);

SvgIcon.propTypes = {
  stroke: PropTypes.oneOf(Object.values(SVG_ICON_COLORS)),
  fill: PropTypes.oneOf(Object.values(SVG_ICON_COLORS)),
  size: PropTypes.oneOf(Object.values(SVG_ICON_SIZES)),
  icon: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
};

export default SvgIcon;
```